# Forming DataFrames from CSV files with different headers in Spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a folder of Gzipped CSV's (without extension) with a list of variables. e.g.:

`CSV file 1: TIMESTAMP | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3`

`CSV file 2: TIMESTAMP | VAR1 | VAR3`

Each file represents a day. The order of the columns can be different (or there can be missing columns on one file).

The first option of reading the whole folder on one shot using `spark.read` is discarded  because the join between the files is taking into account the column order and not the column names. 
My next options is to read by file:

```
 for (String key : pathArray) {
       Dataset<Row> rawData = spark.read().option("header", true).csv(key);
       allDatasets.add(rawData);
    }
```

And then do a full outer join on the column names:

```
Dataset<Row> data = allDatasets.get(0);
     for (int i = 1; i < allDatasets.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> columns = new 
        ArrayList(Arrays.asList(data.columns()));
        columns.retainAll(new  
        ArrayList(Arrays.asList(allDatasets.get(i).columns())));
        data = data.join(allDatasets.get(i), 
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(columns), "outer");
      }
```

But this process is **very slow** as it loads a file at a time.

The next approach is to use `sc.binaryFiles` as with `sc.readFiles` is not possible to make a workaround for adding custom Hadoop codecs(in order to be able to read Gzipped files without the `gz` extension).

Using the latest approach and translating [this code](https://bitbucket.org/zero323/spark-multifile-targz-extract)  to Java  I have the following:

- A `JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>>>` containing the name of the variable (`VAR1`) and a iterable of tuples `TIMESTAMP,VALUE` for that `VAR`.

I would like to form with this a DataFrame representing all the files, however I am completely lost on how to transform this final PairRDD to a Dataframe. The DataFrame should represent the contents of all the files together. And example of the final DataFrame that I would like to have is the following:

```
  TIMESTAMP | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 
   01           32      12    32  ==> Start of contents of file 1
   02           10       5     7  ==> End of contents of file 1
   03                    1     5  ==> Start of contents of file 2
   04                    4     8  ==> End of contents of file 2
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it with very good performance:

1. Reading by month in "background" (using a Java `Executor` to read in parallel other folders with CSV's), with this approach the time that the `Driver` takes while scanning each folder is reduced because is done in parallel.
2. Next, the process follows extracting on the one hand the headers and on the other hand their contents (tuples with varname, timestamp, value).
3. Finally, union the contents using the `RDD` API and make the Dataframe with the headers.